# Group Input node and selecting / choosing Drop-down List items with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Group Input node and selecting / choosing drop-down list items with Geometry Nodes

I can select different objects using `Compare` node and `Switch` node and typing in $0$, $1$, $2$ to get the selection I want.

See Below:

[image: img1]

How can I do the same thing with nodes that have drop-down lists?

**Example:** I want to add another selection to the `Group Input` node that allows me to choose / select between **point**, **edge**, **face**, **etc...**  If this is not possible Is there a workaround?

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

Comment: This is currently not possible. There is an ongoing [design talk](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/enum-sockets-proposal/21318) by the developers. You can however do the same thing you do right now, using switch nodes and plug in duplicates of the Sample Index node with the different enum items selected